# void android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-activity, view, nullpointerexception

I have an Activity A [MainActivity] from which I start Activity B [Videoplayer]
**Case 1:** Click a video thumbnail from Activity A => Goes to Activity B => Play video for few seconds (important: you need to play the video for few seconds) => Click Back navigation => comes back to Activity A => **No crash**.

**Case 2:** Click a video thumbnail from Activity A => Goes to Activity B => Buffers and video starts to play => immediately Click Back navigation (important: do not play the video) => app tries to come back to Activity A => **Crashes and its consistent**.

**Note:** I have no code written in onResume() of Activity A, just to ensure that I haven't overridden any onResume() related code, which might lead to crash.
The stacktrace does not point to a line in app code, it just shows a stacktrace from android source lib. I have spent more than **4+hrs** on this, any help is appreciated.

**Activity B [Player Activity] code:**

```
public class VitamioPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener {
public static final String TAG = VitamioPlayerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Bind(R.id.videoView)
VideoView videoView;

@Bind(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Bind(R.id.subtitle_view)
TextView mSubtitleView;

private VideoModel videoModel;
private long mPosition = 0;

private boolean isLiveChannel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vitamio);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    if (getIntent() == null)
        return;

    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
        return;

    if (!getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(AppConstant.KEY_BUNDLE_VIDEO))
        return;

    videoModel = (VideoModel) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(AppConstant.KEY_BUNDLE_VIDEO);
    if (videoModel == null)
        return;

    playVideo();
}


VideoControllerView controllerView;

void playVideo() {
    String path = null;
    if (videoModel.isLoadBalancer()) {
        path = URLHelper.getInstance().getPlayableVideoUrl(videoModel.getVideoUrl());
    } else
        path = videoModel.getVideoUrl();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please edit MediaPlayer Activity, " + "and set the path variable to your media file path." + " Your media file must be stored on sdcard.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    isLiveChannel = !(path.contains(".mp4"));
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoView.setMediaController(controllerView = new VideoControllerView(this, !isLiveChannel));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
}

@Override
public void onTimedText(String text) {
    mSubtitleView.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void onTimedTextUpdate(byte[] pixels, int width, int height) {
    int a = 1;
}


@Nullable
@OnClick(R.id.imvHeaderBack)
void doBack() {
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (mPosition > 0) {
        videoView.seekTo((int) mPosition);
        mPosition = 0;
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    WindowUtils.getInstance().genericInfoMsgWithOKCallBack(this, null, "Sorry, Cannot Play Video", R.color.redStatus,
            new ViewConstructor.InfoDisplayListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPositiveSelection(DialogInterface alertDialog) {
                    doBack();
                }
            });
    return true;
}
```

}

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1310)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6050)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5442)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: please add ActivityB code

Comment: If it crashes on A, please add A activity code. And is there another informations in logcat ? I once encountered something like that where the problem was "in android code"... I had to debug it by manually removing lines (in onResume/OnActivityResult, ...) code in order to find the exact line calling the functions incorrectly (probably passing a null pointer) leading to the bug. I think you should try that.

Comment: okay @Feuby I am adding activity A code too and 1 more point if i debug it wont crash. time is the one playing tricks on one, you would notice if you read my question carefully

Comment: @DJphy, do you have any scrollbars in your hierarchy? Like `ScrollView` or some other view, that has scrollbars attached to it. Disable scrollbars and try that way.

Comment: @azizbekian okay I will check on this, sounds intresting, i have a scrollview in Activity A i guess so, thnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking the docs a bit more, it looks like you're falling into this scenario from the onCreate docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest of the activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.

Since your `onBackPressed` and `doBack` both call `finish()`, you're likely encountering a race condition where `videoView` is still starting in your activity's `onCreate`, back is pressed before `onCreate` is over and your activity gets destroyed while it's trying to play the `videoView` while skipping all the other lifecycle functions, leading to a crash with this odd stack trace.

**FIX: Override `onResume` and call `videoView.start` in there and override `onDestroy` and `onStop` and call `if (videoView.isPlaying()) videoView.stopPlayback` in there**

Comment: oh okay, will give it a try

Comment: I am fortunate to get an answer from you, golden words that i will remember the rest of my journey as App Dev - "Activity finish before onCreate() is completed". Keep up the good work, I read this **"subsequently answering questions to help fill in the holes to problems that didn't already have solutions out there"** and yes you did it. Thnx again

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you! Thanks for the check mark :-)